# Does answering no when asked to have/adopt a child lower my relationship score with my spouse?

Tags: stardew-valley

As the title says; is there a relationship penalty to my spouse if I say no to having a kid and if so, how much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a kid or not does not affect your relationship score